# What is happening when I do an indirect approach to multiply a scalar with a trignometric function and get an accurate result?

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification, average

So here is what I am doing:

 I have ($ 215 \times \sin 22^\circ $) which has the correct answer $ \rightarrow 80.5404 \approx 81 $

---

Now I perform the following procedure:

$ \sin 22^\circ $ is not known, but it lies between $ \sin0^\circ \text{ and } \sin 30^\circ $

*i.e* $$ \sin0^\circ < \sin22^\circ < \sin30^\circ $$

We know, $ \ \sin0^\circ = 0 \text{ and } \sin30^\circ = \frac1 2$

 Taking average of: $\ \sin0^\circ \text{ & } \sin30^\circ $
$$\implies \sin22^\circ \approx \frac{ \sin0^\circ + \sin30^\circ}{2} $$
$$\implies \sin22^\circ \approx \frac{0+ 0.5}{2} = \frac 1 4 $$

$\therefore 215 \times \cfrac 1 4 = 53.75  \text{   ...(i)}$

[ I have no reason why did this step and onwards, but I guess I was just experimenting with math]

And $ 215 \times \cfrac 1 2 = 107.5 \text{   ...(ii)} \ \ \ \ $      [ basically, $ \sin30 $]

Taking the average of eq (i) and (ii), *i.e*
$$ \cfrac{53.75+107.5}{2} = 80.625 \approx 81 $$

 Which almost matches with the calculator answer  $80.5404$

---

Can anyone please explain how come my answer was ***so close***, what was I doing and whats happening?

Comment: Hard to tell what's happening. Why did you choose $215$ out of any other option?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path OP said they wish to compute $215\times\sin(22^\circ)$

Comment: @DavidM. Did he? I didn't take "I have" to stand for "I need to calculate": I thought it was just a remark.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Fair enough. I interpreted it to mean they were trying to compute it

Comment: Probably a combination of two things:  secant line approximations and the fact that $\sin x \approx x$ for small $x$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path, DavidM. is right. I did wish to compute $ 215 \times \sin(22) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is that

$$\sin(22^\circ)\approx0.3746, $$

which you're approximating with the average of the quantities

$$ A=\sin(30^\circ)=\frac{1}{2} $$

and

$$ B = \frac{\sin(0^\circ)+\sin(30^\circ)}{2}=\frac{1}{4}. $$

We have that

$$ \frac{A+B}{2}=\frac{3}{8}=0.375, $$

which is close to $0.3746\approx\sin(22^\circ)$.

Comment: so was it a coincidence?

Comment: I thought the averages had to do something with it, in general.

Comment: I think it was a coincidence. If you do the same thing for, say $\sin(21^\circ)$, it won't work as well.